# Update Mysql Query Optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I must create a mysql query with a large number of queries (about 150,000)

For the moment the query is:

```
UPDATE table SET activated=NULL
WHERE (
        id=XXXX
    OR  id=YYYY 
    OR  id=ZZZZ 
    OR  id=...
    ...
)
AND activated IS NOT NULL
```

Do you know a best way for to do that please?

Comment: Where are the id's coming from, is it user driven or data driven?

Comment: Data driven, why it's important?

Comment: Because instead of having a giant or constructor you could do something like update [table] set activated = null from [table] t join myIDs i on i.id = t.id which would be a lot faster than running a statement with a hundred or conditions on a number of thousands of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about thousands of items, an `IN` clause probably isn't going to work.  In that case you would want to insert the items into a temporary table, then join with it for the update, like so:

```
UPDATE table tb
JOIN temptable ids ON ids.id = tb.id
SET tb.activated = NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table 
SET activated = NULL
WHERE id in ('XXXX', 'YYYY', 'zzzz')
AND activated IS NOT NULL
```